# How to split item names when writing csv file of scraped data

Tags: r, excel, csv, web-scraping

I am interested in creating a csv or similar Excel-compliant file with data that I scraped from the web by using R. So far I stored the data by doing this:

```
require(textreadr)
spiegel <- read_html("http://www.spiegel.de/schlagzeilen/")
headlines <- html_nodes(spiegel, ".headline-date")
mydata <- html_text(headlines)
```

The variable "mydata" now contains the following:

```
[1] "(Wirtschaft, 00:00)"       "(Kultur, 23:42)"           "(Sport, 23:38)"            "(Politik, 23:16)"         
  [5] "(Sport, 22:29)"            "(Panorama, 21:56)"         "(Sport, 21:39)"            "(Sport, 21:25)"           
  [9] "(Sport, 20:23)"            "(Politik, 20:21)"          "(Politik, 20:09)"          "(Wissenschaft, 19:41)"
```

When I use write.csv now I want to create two columns, the first one should contain the categories like "Wirtschaft, Sport, etc." and the second one the time. Can someone tell me how to do this specifically in this case?

Comment: Tagged [tag:web-scraping]. Don't tag it [tag:rstudio] unless it specifically involves the IDE, which this doesn't.

Comment: Also, so we know which package `read_html()` comes from and can run your code, `require(texteadr)` anytime you use a nondefault package.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parentheses, convert to a tibble (whose since column will be called `value`) and use `separate` to split that into two columns.  Finally write it out. Replace `stdout()` with your filename.

```
Lines <- c("(Wirtschaft, 00:00)", "(Kultur, 23:42)") # test data

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

Lines %>% 
      gsub("[()]", "", .) %>%
      as.tibble %>%
      separate(value, into = c("Name", "Time"), sep = ", ") %>%
      write.csv(stdout(), row.names = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
"Name","Time"
"Wirtschaft","00:00"
"Kultur","23:42"
```

Comment: That looks absolutely great! Thanks a lot. However, right now I cannot figure out how to implement this if I do not want to use just the two data dataframes but the whole variable with around 200. Can someone help me with this as well? Thanks again.

Comment: I just cannot solve it... I tried so many times already. What I specifically do not get is the first line: Why would you use c(...) and then I do not get the separate command. I would be so grateful if someone could help me here.

Comment: The first line creates some sample data since the question did not provide the input in reproducible form.   `c("A", "B")` is a character vector of length 2 consisting of `"A"` and `"B"`.  Make sure the indicated packages are installed and then just copy the code exactly as it is in the answer to the clipboard and then paste it into your  R session and you should see the same answer.

Comment: Yeah. I do but what I was asking for involves more "observations". I have around 200 and I really need to know how to  do the same thing based on the first lines of codes that I posted. Starting with the variable "mydata" in my case. Would be great if you could help me out.

Comment: The same code works whether the character vector `Lines` contains 2 elements as in the answer or 200 elements.   Note that your question exhibits `mydata` as a character vector and so that was what was used in everyone's answers.  If you did not post what you intended then you can ensure that it is in reproducible form by cutting your input down to a small size and then showing the output of `dput(mydata)` in the question where `mydata` is the cut down version of your object.

Comment: Ok. So it seems that it does not work with "mydata" because it is a character vector. All I am asking and really this is all I want to achieve right now is: To use this variable and do the same thing that you did with "lines". This is all I want right now, really. Please just help me to figure out how to do it. Do I have to transform it, do I have to scrape the data differentely, just tell me because I am extremely frustrated right now.

Comment: You know I am also willing to learn about it. Just tell me there is a video about data manipulation that is good or any tutorial.... but I really need help

Comment: Waiting for the `dput` output that was requested.

Comment: I cant put it here. It is too long.

Comment: c("(Sport, 22:01)", "(Politik, 22:00)", "(Sport, 21:22)", 
"(Sport, 20:41)", [...] "(Politik, 00:15)")

Comment: Its like this. Imagine more in the [...]

Comment: In that case you do have a character vector as input so the code already provided by myself as well as the other answer should work.  Note that the dput output should be in the question and not in the comments and the dput output should not be abbreviated. You should cut it down BEFORE running dput.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `base R` using `read.csv` after replacing the `()` with blank (`""`) with `gsub`

```
df1 <- read.csv(text = gsub("[()]", "", mydata), header = FALSE,
          col.names = c("Col1", "Col2"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(df1)
#      Col1   Col2
#1   Kultur  23:42
#2    Sport  23:38
#3  Politik  23:16
#4    Sport  22:29
#5 Panorama  21:56
#6    Sport  21:39

tail(df1)
#          Col1   Col2
#189 einestages  04:26
#190   Panorama  04:26
#191      Sport  04:09
#192    Politik  03:11
#193    Politik  01:56
#194    Politik  00:15
```

Comment: Seems dangerous, what if the title had spaces in it, e.g. "Arts and Literature"? Or a comma?

Comment: akrun nonsense. It's just sloppy to assume there is only one whitespace to split on, when instead you just need to split on the rightmost comma. That works no matter how many spaces and commas the data has.

Comment: akrun you're an accomplished coder, dude. Why write bad code when we can right good code...

Comment: @smci  Here, I splitted based on the `,`..  You are saying that if there is a comma in between the words.  In that case, `do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(mydata, ",\\s(?=\\d)|[()]", perl = TRUE), '[', 2:3))`  Here, I didn't find a situation like that.  In general, the patterns can be anything.  If we chase for that, it will be an endless game

Comment: @smci, There is no point in introducing complexity to the answer when it is not needed.  If one needed to handle comma in the field content I would have expected that the question give such an example and that the fields would be bracketed by quotes since the format shown in the question is not very sensible otherwise.